# Sum up GridView column based on ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello Friends I need to group the elements of GridView as shown below. 
I need to sum up the price according to its ID's

Data in GridView

## ID1-----ID2-----Price

1-------------1-------------100

2-------------1-------------150

3-------------1-------------120

4-------------2-------------120

5-------------2-------------160

6-------------3-------------100

7-------------3-------------200

I want to group this data as shown below and save it in a datatable so that I can pass it to my Database.

## ID2-----Price

1------------370

2------------280

3------------300

How do I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: how you bind the gridview? can you update the code?

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = Fetching data from Database;
GridView.Datasource = dt;
GridView.Bind();

Now my data is in GV and the user can make changes in the Price column. After that I need to group the data based on the second ID and get the sum of Price.

Answer (score 2):

change your select statement as below

```
SELECT ID2, SUM(Price) FROM TableName GROUP BY ID2
```

you can do as below if you need to read from gridview

```
List<Record> records = new Record<Record>();

foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   // below code need to be change with your grid controls and id names, and add validations for handle null values etc..
   string id2 = ((Label)row.FindControl("ID2Label")).Text;
   string Price = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("PricetextBox")).Text;
   records.Add(new Record(){ ID2 = int.Parse(id2), Price = int.Parse(Price)});       
}

var results = records.GroupBy(r=>r.ID2)
                    .Select(g=> new Record(){ ID2 = g.Key, Price = g.Sum(x=>x.Price)})
                    .ToList();
```

you may need helper class like below

```
public class Record
{
    public int ID2 { get; set;}
    public int Price {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hello @Damith, thanks for the response. I am binding data in the gridview. After that user can change the price. So i need to group/sum based on the second ID (ID2)

Comment: @Sid in same gridview?

Comment: No, I want the result in a datatable so that I can save it.

Comment: Reading data from GridView  depend on how you bind data and your aspx page controls, please update the question

Comment: Ya sorry for that. I ve updated/edited the question.